React Form Submits Cause Page Reload Despite Using e.preventDefault() https://github.com/hatimb03/Murmur---chat-app.git
I'm working on a React component with a form that sends a message using a custom hook. Despite using e.preventDefault() in the form's onSubmit handler, the page reloads every time I submit the form, which interrupts my debugging process and resets the state. I've verified that e.preventDefault() is being called correctly, and there are no additional forms or submit buttons on the page that could be causing this behavior. I'm not seeing any JavaScript errors in the console that could explain this issue. I've also checked that the form is set up correctly, with the button type as submit.
here's the component
`

import { FaSearch } from "react-icons/fa";
import useSendMessage from "../../hooks/useSendMessage";
import { useState } from "react";

const SearchInput = () => {
  const { loading, sendMessage } = useSendMessage();
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");

  const handleMessageSend = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevents default page reload

    if (!message) return;
    await sendMessage(message);
    setMessage("");
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleMessageSend}>`
      <input`
        type="text"
        value={message}
        onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
        placeholder="Type a message"
      />
      <button type="submit">
        {loading ? <span>Loading...</span> : <FaSearch />}
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default SearchInput;`

any insights would be helpful
What I Tried:
I set up a React form with an onSubmit handler that calls e.preventDefault() to stop the page from reloading. I implemented a custom hook to handle sending messages via an API. I also verified that the form was correctly configured, with the submit button type set to "submit".
What I Expected:
I expected the form to submit the message asynchronously without reloading the page. The state should update with the new message, and the input field should reset to an empty string.
What Actually Happened:
Despite calling e.preventDefault(), the page still reloads every time I submit the form, which resets the component state and interrupts the form submission process. I can't debug the issue properly because the page reload prevents me from seeing console logs or tracking state changes.
here's my useSendMessage
import toast from "react-hot-toast";
import useConversations from "../zustand/useConversations";
import { useState } from "react";

const useSendMessage = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const { messages, setMessages, selectedConversation } = useConversations();

  const sendMessage = async (message) => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const res = await fetch(
        `/api/messages/send/${selectedConversation._id}`,
        {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({ message }),
        }
      );

      const data = await res.json();
      if (data.error) throw new Error(data.error);

      setMessages([...messages, data]);
    } catch (error) {
      toast.error(error.message);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  return { loading, sendMessage };
};

export default useSendMessage;


here's zustand
import { create } from "zustand";

const useConversations = create((set) => ({
  selectedConversation: null,
  setSelectedConversation: (selectedConversation) =>
    set({ selectedConversation }),
  messages: [],
  setMessages: (messages) => set({ messages }),
}));

export default useConversations;



I do not see any overt issue with this code. I reproduced it on my end and it works fine and doesn't refresh the page on form submission. Perhaps, you can include the code for the useSendMessage() hook to see if the issue might be coming from there.

Also please try e.stoppropogation() for any event to stop from propagating to top level.

I tried to set some values in localstorage to check if the e.preventDefault() works, and i dont see any values being set in the locastorage, except the user-info, which i saved after login

I need you to write this on code sandbox and share a link add as little as u can until this issue happens

Your are not passing event to the handleMessageSend function.
Change this line and it should work:
onSubmit={(e) => handleMessageSend(e)}

Still doesn't work

I see the problem, after you send the message you set the message to an empty string which updates the state and cause re-evaluation of component. Try to remove setMessage("") in SearchInput component and also do not forget to pass the event to the handleMessageSend function

Nope, doesnt work !

Is it possible that another form is wrapping your component? If that is the case, the parent form is reloading your page.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Add an action to the form to see if it is really submitting it or something else is causing the page to reload:
<form action="http://www.google.com">

Also check if you aren't wrapping your whole page in an <a href> somewhere.
Also check that you don't have an absolutely positioned <a href> overlapping your form that is part of another widget somewhere.
